# NULL and DEFAULT value: MySql behavior does not seem coherent

Tags: mysql

I am investigating the behavior of MySQL with NULL and DEFAULT keywords applied in different combinations but there is some behavior I cannot understand.

```
CREATE TABLE nullcheck 
(column1 varchar(10) NOT NULL, column2 varchar(10), column3 int NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO nullcheck VALUES 
("a", "b", 3), 
("a", NULL, 5), 
(NULL, "b", 2),
("a", "b", NULL)
```

column1, column2, column3 
a,b,3
a,NULL,5
,b,2
a,b,0

So default values are taken for each data type. This is fine.

Let's got for another table.

```
CREATE TABLE defaultcheck
(column1 varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
column2 varchar(10) DEFAULT "Ciao", 
column3 int NOT NULL DEFAULT 99)
INSERT INTO defaultcheck (column1, column2) VALUES  ("a", "b")
INSERT INTO defaultcheck (column1, column3) VALUES  ("a", 25)
```

column1, column2, column3
a,b,99
a,Ciao,25

And again this is fine, as default values are working correctly.
One more statement:

```
INSERT INTO defaultcheck (column1, column2, column3) VALUES  ("a", “b”, NULL)
```

**Here I get an error, as NULL value cannot be assigned to the non nullable column3. 
First question: why MySQL is not assigning the default value, like in the previous table, when the default clause was implicit?**

One last statement:

```
INSERT INTO defaultcheck (column1, column2, column3) VALUES  (NULL, “b”, 25)
```

Also in this case I get an error, given that column1 cannot be NULL.
Second question: why MySQL is not behaving like in the first table, where not specifying a default value for a not nullable column leads to an insertion with an implicitly set default value?

Thanks.

PS I am using PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: With the expression `VALUES  ('a','b', NULL)` you **explicitly** state "*I do **want** a `NULL` value in that column*" - and MySQL rightfully rejects that requests because *you* defined the column as `NOT NULL`

Comment: You need to retest these cases using different sql_modes, especially `STRICT_ALL_TABLES` mode and `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` mode, see this link for details:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: Are you sure with your INSERT statement for nullcheck table, Because it doesn't even get compiled on my machine..?

Comment: @AmiteshRai Yes it works for me on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE nullcheck (column1 varchar(10) NOT NULL, column2 varchar(10), column3 int NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE defaultcheck (column1 varchar(10) NOT NULL, column2 varchar(10) DEFAULT "Ciao", column3 int NOT NULL DEFAULT 99)

If you say 'column3 int NOT NULL' it can't be Null;

Here:

```
    INSERT INTO defaultcheck (column1, column2, column3) VALUES  ("a", “b”, NULL)

or

INSERT INTO defaultcheck (column1, column2, column3) VALUES  (NULL, “b”, 25)
```

You are "forcing" to insert null value in a field that can't be null, it has default value, ok, but you are overriding default value with null.
Same with second question, if you set a field NOT NULL, it never can be null, if you force a NULL when it can't be NULL an error will appear.

Edit bot inserts in OP are INTO defaultcheck.

Comment: I understand your first answer, but not the second: in the first table I do not setup a default value and, when trying to insert NULL, I do NOT get an error, but rather the default value for the field I tried to set to NULL. In the second table, under the same condition, I get an error.

Comment: in OP both inserts are for defaultcheck, is it correct?

Comment: Then modify OP, there both inserts are for the same table.

Comment: They are correct. I mean the first block of inserts is for nullcheck, the second block ofinserts is for defaultcheck, where I test also NULL values.